# Android Kotlin - Change fade in duration when start activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the file `fade_in.xml` in the `res > anim` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="100" />
```

And this is how I start the activity:

```
val i = Intent(this, ChooseUpload::class.java)
startActivity(i)
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
```

The fade in duration is always the same no matter what value I set in `android:duration=`, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `android.R.anim.fade_in` - the framework version of the `fade_in` animation, not your `fade_in` Animation. You'll want to remove the `android.` prefixes to use your resources:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the wrong `fade_in` file. Change:

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
```

to

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
```

One final check you can perform is to right-click on `fade_in` (in the line above) and go to the exact place it was declared just to make sure you're referring the right file.